# module.default is undefined dynamic import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use React.lazy to lazy load a React Component.
The component looks like this:

```
function App() {
const HubScreen = React.lazy(() => import("./screens/hub").then((mod) => {
    console.log(mod.default)
    return mod.default;
}));

return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MainContaier>
                <div id="screen">
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Switch>
                        <React.Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
                            <Route path="/hub" render={() => <HubScreen />} />
                        </React.Suspense>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </MainContaier>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter >
) 
}
```

And this is the component I'm importing

```
import React from "react";

function HubScreen() {
  return (
      <div>Hi</div>
  );
}

export default HubScreen;
```

When I navigate to `/hub` I see the value of `mod.default` as undefined. Along with my Chrome window becoming completely unresponsive, requiring a force stop.

I know that my path to the module `./screens/hub`, is correct because, if I put a fake path like `./screens/hube` then webpack gives me the error:

```
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './screens/hube' in '/home/travis/Workspace/avalon/assets/js'
```

I'm stumped haven't found a similar problem anywhere.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698239/2801159) gave me some insight as to why my browser was hanging up. However I still seem to have the same root problem; the undefined module.default. After changing the root component to this:

```
const HubScreen = React.lazy(() => import("./screens/hub"));

function App() {
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MainContaier>
                <div id="screen">
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Switch>
                        <React.Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
                            <Route path="/hub" component={HubScreen} />
                        </React.Suspense>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </MainContaier>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter >
)
}
```

I get the War:

```
Warning: lazy: Expected the result of a dynamic import() call. Instead received: [object Object]

Your code should look like: 
  const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'))
```

And then the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Promise elements must resolve to a class or function.
```

Which I have taken to mean that undefined is being returned from the import resolution, as the console.log seems to confirm.

Answer (score 12):

Also another possibility of getting this error is by missing the default export in your Component which becomes a named export.

This syntax is only supported for Default exports.

`const HubScreen = React.lazy(() => import("./screens/hub"));`

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const ChangeName = (props) => {

    return (
    <div>

      <p>Name: {props.name}</p>
      <p>Email: {props.email}</p>

      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>props.changeStatus()}>Change Details</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }


  export default ChangeName; ====> By missing the default Export
```

Comment: thanks, man! default export was missing.

Answer (score 1):

First off, move your `const HubScreen` outside of your component. When `App()` rerenders, it will cause an infinate loop to keep trying to load `HubScreen` over and over again. Secondly, just use `() => import...` and let `React.lazy` use the default component exported. Additionally, you should not need to use render for the route. Just provide the component:

```
const HubScreen = React.lazy(() => import("./screens/hub"));

function App() {

return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MainContaier>
                <div id="screen">
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Switch>
                        <React.Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
                            <Route path="/hub" component={HubScreen} />
                        </React.Suspense>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </MainContaier>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter >
    ) 
}
```

Comment: The reloading of `./screens/hub` explains why my browser is hanging up. But I still have the problem of the default export being undefined. I added the `then` so I could log out what was going on with the import. With the code above I get an error that seems to be complaining about the default export being undefined. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @TravisSmith `console.log(HubScreen)` right before the export. Make sure you have no typos, and tell me what you see in the console when it tries to load.

Comment: It doesn't even hit the log at all. I changed to `const HubScreen = require("./screens/hub")`  and then I saw the log: `ƒ HubScreen() {
  return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", null, "Hi");
}`. But when using `React.lazy` log doesn't get called at all. Additionally this might be relevant. Using the `require` syntax gives me the same error. But, using `import HubScreen from "./screens/hub"` renders the component.

Comment: Try: `const HubScreen = React.lazy(() => require("./screens/hub"));`

Comment: If I do that I see the log but I get an error: `Uncaught null` and later `Uncaught TypeError: _thenable.then is not a function`

Comment: @TravisSmith At this point, you should move your code to github, or generate a sandbox example, so that I can attempt to reproduce your issue. `React.lazy(() => import("./screens/hub"));` *should* work. `console.log(React.lazy)`. Are you on the latest version of React?

Comment: React 16.6.3, I'll post a link soon

Comment: anyone has this problem with class components?
I'm trying to do it but getting the same error, but cant use functional components to display the data